# Xcode 7 Performance Test Measurements

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, performance-testing

I've written some unit tests to measure the time it takes for my app to create and load view controllers using a `measure` block. This gives me a result which displays a grey tick, the standard deviation and the whether the result is better or worse than my current baseline.

This information is great, but is there anyway to make the test fail if the `measureBlock` runs a certain percentage worse than the baseline? I'd like to add these tests to my automated test suite but I haven't found a way to log these results programatically or cause the tests to fail under certain conditions yet.

Comment: Xcode 8??? Huh. Unless you work in Apple, then surely the latest Xcode available is Xcode 7.1 (beta)?

Comment: Apologies, I meant to write Xcode 7.